# Why is Stripe::Checkout not working in rails 7 after the url has been redirected

Tags: ruby, url, redirect, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to redirect to stripe checkout but when I redirect I get an error from stripe saying something is wrong.

I Have this code that creates a `Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({})` It looks like this:

```rb
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  def overview
    id = params[:id]
    cart = Cart.find((session[id]['cart_id']))
    
    @checkout = Checkout.new(cart, currency)
    session[:stripe] = @checkout.set_stripe
    session.delete(id)

    case pay_method
    when 'stripe'
      puts "It is Stripe"
      @link_path = stripe_path
      @link_name = "Stripe"
    else
      puts "It is Else but Defaults to stripe"
      @link_path = stripe_path
      @link_name = "Stripe"
    end
  end

  def stripe    
    @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: session[:stripe],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: success_url,
      cancel_url: cancel_url,
    })
    redirect_to @session.url, allow_other_host: true
  end
end
```

Inside `@checkout.set_stripe` it looks like this:

```rb
class Checkout
  def initialize(cart, currency)
    @cart = cart
    @curr = currency
  end

  def get_cart
    return @cart
  end

  # Create the stripe format
  def set_stripe
    result = Array.new
    get_cart.get_products.each do |get_product|
      product = get_product.product
      result<<({
        :price_data => {
          :currency => @curr, 
          :unit_amount => product.price, 
          :product_data => {
            :name => product.name
          }
        }, 
        :quantity => get_product.quantity
      })
    end
    return result
  end
end
```

Everything seem to be right and `line_items` gets populated correctly, but when I try to redirect to the `@session.url` the stripe url loads but then it shows:

> Something went wrong. The page you were looking for could not be found. Please check the URL or contact the merchant.

And the terminal prints this:

```sql
Started GET "/stripe" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-25 01:43:27 -0400
Processing by CheckoutController#stripe as HTML
  Cart Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `initialize_cart'
Redirected to https:// checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a_whole_line_of_string_that_I_dont_think_I_should_share
Completed 302 Found in 1023ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 5211)
```

## =====
EDIT====

I looked at my console log and I see a bunch of Content Security Policy errors like this:

```js
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“script-src”).
Source: window.__cmp && typeof __cmp("getCMPData…
```

And I also get error saying:

```
The resource at “https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/checkout-app-init--bunch-of-string.js” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.
```

Comment: It doesn't relate to ruby nor rails itself.

Try to access created session directly by URL.

Go to: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments/, find a related PaymentIntent object (probably the latest), go to inside the object and explore related Log request. Inside the response section you should found an "URL" param. That is exactly what you have in your controller. Is your session is accessible by the URL?

Comment: When I click the redirect that my terminal prints out it does work and it opens up to the stripe payment page. But when I look for the url in the stripe response section, it shows `"url": null`. How do I make the session.url accessible if it is not already.

Comment: Hm. Looks strange. I've reproduced your entire scenario (not script) and was successful. Session URL work correct in my case. Try to change `redirect_to @session.url` to json render like: `render json: @session` and look at the result.

Comment: I checked out the `render json: @session` and the `@session.url` does have a corresponding link attached to it. Is it possible for there to be something in my code that is preventing this sequence from working properly?

Comment: How are the success/cancel urls generated?

Comment: I have these 2 gets, `get 'success', to: 'checkout#success'` and `get 'cancel', to: 'checkout#cancel'` which are represented correctly in the json file as `"http://localhost:3000/cancel"` and `"http://localhost:3000/success"`

Comment: > "and the @session.url does have a corresponding link attached to it"
What does it exactly mean? Does the URL you've seen is available and lends to the Stripe checkout page or not? If so - the problem is in redirect_to call. If you didn't get a working URL - the problem in Stripe checkout API calls.